# PHP cannot compare strings

Tags: php, templates, drupal-7

This is such a basic thing, I can't believe I can't figure it out. I have a php variable in a template file, call it `$author`. It gets passed in by the content management system I'm using. I'm pretty sure it's a string. It's value is **'John'**

The reason why I think it's a string is because when I try

```
<?php print gettype($author); ?>
```

it prints 'string'
When I write

```
<?php print $author; ?>
```

**'John'** gets printed
However, when I write

```
<?php $author == 'John' ? print 'yes' : print 'no'; ?>
```

it prints **'no'**. Wait.. what?
Also when I use

```
<?php print strcmp($author, 'John'); ?>
```

The function returns -14!
I guess my questions are, what is going on here? And how can I test if `$author is equal to 'John'?`
If it matters, the content management system is drupal, however I think it's more of a general php question.

Comment: And now do `var_dump($author)`

Comment: Yeah, var_dump will dump the error out

Comment: Maybe $author contains some control character/white space?
Try `trim($author)`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. When I did var_dump I got very unexpected results.. but the answer was obvious if I had noticed it inspect element, I usually would have noticed it .. just late I guess. "trim" was the first I tried, but turns out it was wrapped in a <span> so 'strip_tags' did the trick .. I feel kinda dumb now haha but I guess I'll leave the question up in case it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Force it to be a string.

```
<?php
$author = (string)$author;
$author == 'John' ? print 'yes' : print 'no';
?>
```

Comment: I gave that a try, but turns out it just had some extra characters that I didn't notice in inspect element (guess it was kinda late), .. var_dump rooted out the difference. I'm leaving the question up in case it helps someone though.

Comment: @Benjamin Thvedt Happens all the time hehe :). Good it works now.